# Tensorflow. How to distribute ops between GPUs

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I am running a very large Tensorflow model on google cloud ml-engine.
When using the scale tier `basic_gpu` (with `batch_size=1`) I get errors like:

> Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1,155,240,240,16]

because the model is too large to fit in one GPU.

Using the tier `comple_model_m_gpu` which provides 4 GPUs I can spread the operations between the 4 GPUs.

However, I remember reading that communication between GPUs is slow and can create a bottleneck in training. Is this true?

If so, is there a recommended way of spreading operations between the GPUs that prevents this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend the following guide:

[Optimizing for GPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide#optimizing_for_gpu)

From the guide:

> The best approach to handling variable updates depends on the model, 
>   hardware, and even how the hardware has been configured.

A few suggestions based on the guide:

- Try using P100s which have 16 GB of RAM (compared to 12 on the K80s). They are also significantly faster, although they also cost more
- Place the variables on CPU:  `tf.train.replica_device_setter(worker_device=worker, ps_device='/cpu:0', ps_tasks=1)`

Comment: The approach used in guide makes copies of the model across the GPUs each processing different data. My model does not fit in one GPU so I have to use multiple GPUs just for processing one batch. I am using K80. The model is called [VNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.04797)

Comment: Thank you, I am already placing variables on the PS and CPU, I will try the more powerful GPUs. I think the end solution will have to be splitting the input into smaller tensors.

Answer (score 1):

Using Tesla P100 GPUs instead of Tesla K80 GPUs fixes this issue because P100s have something called [Page Migration Engine](http://www.nvidia.com/object/tesla-p100.html).

> Page Migration Engine frees developers to focus more on tuning for
>   computing performance and less on managing data movement. Applications
>   can now scale beyond the GPU's physical memory size to virtually
>   limitless amount of memory.